# Can't login in retropie after update

Tags: keyboard, retropie

[image]I already tryed to resolve this by reading other articles but I can't fix it.
I updated my Retropie last night and as usually when I reboot it asks for login and password, but, when i try to write 'pi' for login it just type squares and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Start with using a better power supply (undervoltage warnings!)

Comment: I know what power supply I'm using and it's just for testing purpose, I already tryed using the original one and it doesn't fix anything

Comment: Then you should post better / more accurate info... FYI undervoltage can cause problems with USB devices not working / not working properly.